# Why can an object be the conditional in an if statement, please explain

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-operator

I've been looking over some code in C++ and came across an object being the boolean conditional for an if statement.  This is confusing to me as it does not seem to fulfill the true/false criteria needed for if statements.  I could understand if the statement was checking for null but the follow code does not make sense to me.

```
if(!mObject)
{
    mObject = new Object();
}
```

Can someone explain why you can do this?

BTW, the code works when it is run.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) The variable is a pointer, and then `!mObject` is true if `mObject` is a null pointer. 2) If `mObject` is an instance of a class or structure, it has overloaded the `!` operator.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Or `operator bool()` (possibly `explicit`)

Comment: Falsy things in C++:  `false`, `0`, `0.0`, `0.0f`, `-0.0`, `-0.0f`, `'\0'`, `nullptr` and other things that evaluate to zero.  (Note:  `NaN` is not falsy in C++.)